# Jndi name connection / Restful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, websphere, jndi

I have to write a very simple RESTful webservice that has to connect database with a jndi

name connection, and the service will be uploaded on websphere application server.

i dont know how to connect database with jndi name, plese help me about this.

Thanks..

Comment: Are you using some Framework? Depending on that, there are several facilities that can be used

Comment: i am using a very simple maven project restful web service that has only one  method in it. The data source was defined on websphere with a jndi name, i need to connect it by using that name.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of: `Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("<jndi-name>");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();`